# C++ Updating a pointer to a sprite's velocity

Tags: c++, pointers, sprite

I'm using a game engine supplied for the course I'm on (which also incorporates OpenGL) and I'm using an array (called basics) to store some enemy sprites. A new sprite is created after 80 frames (I'm sure there's a better way to do this than increment an integer) or rather a pointer to a sprite. In the below example, I want to set the enemy's velocity to move towards the player, except this only runs once because it sets the velocity once it's created, but will never set the same enemy's velocity again.

```
void CMyGame::OnUpdate() //60 frames
{
    if (spawnTime > 80) spawnTime = 0;
    spawnTime++;
    if (spawnTime == 80) 
    {
        CSprite* pBasicEnemy = new CSprite(rand() % 800, 575, basic_texture);
        basics.add( pBasicEnemy);
        basicEnemyVX = player.GetX() - pBasicEnemy->GetX();
        basicEnemyVY = player.GetY() - pBasicEnemy->GetY();
        pBasicEnemy->SetVelocity(basicEnemyVX, basicEnemyVY);
    }
}
```

One thing I've tried is only adding the sprite to array inside the if statement instead of including everything. It runs but strangely, the velocity is not being updated every frame despite it now being local to the OnUpdate() function and not to an if statement.

```
void CMyGame::OnUpdate() //60 Frames
{
    if (spawnTime > 80) spawnTime = 0;
    spawnTime++;
    CSprite* pBasicEnemy = new CSprite(rand() % 800, 575, basic_texture);
    if (spawnTime == 80) 
    {
        basics.add( pBasicEnemy);
    }
    basicEnemyVX = player.GetX() - pBasicEnemy->GetX();
    basicEnemyVY = player.GetY() - pBasicEnemy->GetY();
    pBasicEnemy->SetVelocity(basicEnemyVX, basicEnemyVY);
}
```

Any idea how to somehow update each enemy's velocity every frame?

Comment: The first version, like you said, only sets the velocity once when the sprite is created. The second version creates a new sprite every frame (with the correct velocity), then throws it away except every 81st frame. You want to update the velocity *of the sprite that's already in `basics`*.

Comment: Thanks, but the basics array only have array based member functions like .Size(), .Draw(), .Erase() etc. How do I gain access to the member functions of the pointer to the sprite like .GetX(), .setVelocity() through the basics array? So if I want to access basics[1]'s useful functions like .SetVelocity(), how exactly do I do that?

Comment: There should be an `operator[]` overload (otherwise the library is seriously lacking), i.e. you should be able to do `basics[basics.Size() - 1]` to get the last inserted enemy (although I suggest iterating through all of them so that they all update each frame).